# Three Dimensional Array from Two Dimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the best way to create and populate a three dimensional array by inserting a two dimensional array?

Say I have an array

```
    var arrState = {
        ME: ['Maine','1,328,361'],
            etc
    };
```

And I want to store the current values in that array each time a function is ran. Would something like this work?

```
var arrStateHistory;
var i = 0;

function start(){
i++;
arrHistory[i] = arrState;

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

`arrState` is an object, so you'd have to iterate with `for...in`. Why not use objects for everything?

```
var States = {
  ME: {
    name: 'Maine',
    population: 1328361
  },
  FL: {
    name: 'Florida'
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you can add a new state or modify one like this:

```
States.WA = {
  name: 'Washington',
  population: 1000000
}
```